# Asking User for Inputs and Putting Them in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I created a spreadsheet with a list of movies that I own on disc. I also include the director's last name, first name, runtime, year, language, and format each in separate rows. I'm trying to write code that prompts the user to input a new movie and it's respective attributes in the correct rows.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Create MsgBox that asks user if they would like to add new movie.
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Would you like to add a new movie?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    'If they click Yes
    If answer = vbYes Then
        'Ask for Movie Name and put it in the movies row
        Dim movieName As String

        movieName = InputBox("What is the name of the movie?", "Movie Title", "Please enter movie name")
        movieNameLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(movieNameLR).Value = movieName

        'Ask for Director's last name and put it in Director's last name row
        Dim directorLN As String

        directorLN = InputBox("What is the director's last name?", "Director Last Name", "Please enter director's last name")
        directorLNLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(directorLNLR).Value = directorLN

        'Ask for Director's first name and put it in Director's first name row
        Dim directorFN As String
        directorFN = InputBox("What is the director's first name?", "Director First Name", "Please enter director's first name")
        directorFNLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(directorFNLR).Value = directorFN

        'Ask for Runtime of film and put it in Runtime row
        Dim Runtime As Integer
        Runtime = InputBox("What is the Runtime?", "Runtime", "Please enter Runtime")
        RuntimeLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(RuntimeLR).Value = Runtime

        'Ask for Year and put it in Year row
        Dim Year As Integer
        Year = InputBox("When was the film made?", "Year", "Please enter year")
        YearLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(YearLR).Value = Year

        'Ask for Language and put it in Language row
        Dim Language As String
        Language = InputBox("What language is the film in?", "Language", "Please enter language")
        LanguageLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(LanguageLR).Value = Language

        'Prompt user on whether the film is in Color or Black and White
        Dim Format As String
        Format = MsgBox("Is the film in Color or BW?", "Color" + "BW")

        If Format = "Color" Then
            FormatLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(FormatLR).Value = Color
        Else
            FormatLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(FormatLR).Value = BW
        End If

        'If user clicks no then open spreadsheet
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I get an error when I enter the movie's name into the first input box.

Comment: What is the error? Also, you aren't defining your -LR variables. Not that you explicitly have to, but it's very inconsistent.

Comment: Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object' _Global' failed.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` returns a number. `Range(number)` isn't a valid range.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you.

Comment: What would you recommend to do to convert it into a range object?

Comment: I figured it out using cells instead of range. But the msgbox portion of the code still doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately `"Color" + "BW"` doesn't work like that. You'd need to make a custom userform to have custom buttons on a message box

Comment: If you really don't want to do a userform, then you can look at [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/msgbox-with-custom-buttons.279315/) but a userform is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers.
You can shorten things significantly if you want to. No need to store a bunch of variables you are only going to use once.
You probably don't want to check the last row of every column, since you want all the information for that movie on the same row anyway.
And you probably want to use the row after the last row, or you will just replace the last movie.

When it comes to using last row, you just put that row number together with the column you want to use in a range.

Example, without a userform for the last question:

```
'Create MsgBox that asks user if they would like to add new movie.
Dim answer As Integer, lRow As Long
answer = MsgBox("Would you like to add a new movie?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'If they click Yes
If answer = vbYes Then
    'Ask for Movie Name and put it in the movies row
    Range("A" & lRow).Value = InputBox("What is the name of the movie?", "Movie Title", "Please enter movie name")

    'Ask for Director's last name and put it in Director's last name row
    Range("B" & lRow).Value = InputBox("What is the director's last name?", "Director Last Name", "Please enter director's last name")

    'Ask for Director's first name and put it in Director's first name row
    Range("C" & lRow).Value = InputBox("What is the director's first name?", "Director First Name", "Please enter director's first name")

    'Ask for Runtime of film and put it in Runtime row
    Range("D" & lRow).Value = InputBox("What is the Runtime?", "Runtime", "Please enter Runtime")

    'Ask for Year and put it in Year row
    Range("E" & lRow).Value = InputBox("When was the film made?", "Year", "Please enter year")

    'Ask for Language and put it in Language row
    Range("F" & lRow).Value = InputBox("What language is the film in?", "Language", "Please enter language")

    'Prompt user on whether the film is in Color or Black and White
    Range("G" & lRow).Value = InputBox("Is the film in Color or BW?", "Color/BW")

    'If user clicks no then open spreadsheet
End If
```

If you want a userform, it's easily done. Create a userform and add label and buttons:
[image]

Then you can use a public variable to send the result by using `Public`instead of `dim`, before the sub, not within the sub as with `dim`.

Let's call it `colorChoice`, whatever. and then change the last row to something like:

```
colorMsg.Show
Range("G" & lRow).Value = colorChoice
```

`colorMsg` being the name of the userform ofc.

Then in the userform, the code could be something like:

```
Private Sub bwButton_Click()
colorChoice = "BW"
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub colorBtn_Click()
colorChoice = "Color"
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

or whatever your button names are.

You could also loop through the input boxes to shorten further.
Assuming the top row is appropriate headlines:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    Cells(lRow, i).Value = InputBox(Cells(1, i).Value)
Next i
```